# How to calculate two different types values in single query to show with grouping in PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to display a list under new and renew category with separate total calculation for New and Renew. Also need Grand total to display.
Here is MySql query

```
SELECT * FROM motor WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y %m') = DATE_FORMAT('$selected_year-$selected_month-01', '%Y %m') ORDER BY isnew ASC, date ASC
```

I have separated New and Renew but cannot take Sum of columns.
Here is PHP code

```
    <?php
    if (empty($selected_m_q)){
        echo "<tr><td colspan='7'>$message</td></tr>";
    }else {
        $previous_staus = "";
        $type = "";
        while ($current_m_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($selected_m_q)){
            //var_dump ($current_m_data);
            $status = $current_m_data['isnew'];
            if ($status != $previous_staus){
                if ($status == 1){$type="New";}
                if ($status == 2){$type="Renew";}
                echo "<tr><td colspan='7'>status : $type</td></tr>";
                $previous_staus = $status;
            }
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $current_m_data['date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $current_m_data['policy_no']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $current_m_data['vnumber']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $current_m_data['name']; ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $current_m_data['gpremium']; ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $current_m_data['premium']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="edit-data-m.php?id=<?php echo $current_m_data['id']; ?>">Edit</a> | 
        <!--<input type="button" id="<?php //echo $current_m_data[id]; ?>" class="delete" value="Delete" >-->
        <a href="#" id="<?php echo $current_m_data['id']; ?>" class="delete">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

I want to do is show total of premium column under New and Renew. At the bottom should show total of New and Renew.
Can any one help me on this?

Table motor has below columns

`id`,
  `date`,
  `policy_no`,
  `vnumber`,
  `name`,
  `address`,
  `expected`,
  `gpremium`,
  `premium`,
  `contact_detail`,
  `isnew`

I have tried with calculation but only I can get total for New.

My requirement is like this (Display in a table)

**New**
Few data rows for new status
*Total of premium field for New*
**Renew**
Few data rows under renew status
*Total of premium field for Renew*
**Then Grand Total**

I'm sorry if I made bad writing here. This is my first one.

Comment: could you post the table definition pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop you could just keep a running count of the totals....

```
 <?php
    if (empty($selected_m_q)){
        echo "<tr><td colspan='7'>$message</td></tr>";
    }else {
  >>>>  $previous_status = 1;
        $type = "";
  >>>>  $subTotal = 0;
  >>>>  $grandTotal = 0;
        while ($current_m_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($selected_m_q)){
            //var_dump ($current_m_data);
            $status = $current_m_data['isnew'];
            if ($status != $previous_staus){

>>>>>                
        ?>
            <tr> <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td> 
                 <td><?= $subTotal ?></td> 
                 <td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            $subTotal = 0;
<<<<<

                if ($status == 1){$type="New";}
                if ($status == 2){$type="Renew";}
                echo "<tr><td colspan='7'>status : $type</td></tr>";
                $previous_staus = $status;
            }

  >>>>      $subTotal += $current_m_data['premium'];
  >>>>      $grandTotal += $current_m_data['premium'];
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $current_m_data['date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $current_m_data['policy_no']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $current_m_data['vnumber']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $current_m_data['name']; ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $current_m_data['gpremium']; ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $current_m_data['premium']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="edit-data-m.php?id=<?php echo $current_m_data['id']; ?>">Edit</a> | 
        <!--<input type="button" id="<?php //echo $current_m_data[id]; ?>" class="delete" value="Delete" >-->
        <a href="#" id="<?php echo $current_m_data['id']; ?>" class="delete">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
        }
?>
<tr> <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td> 
     <td><?= $grandTotal ?></td> 
     <td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I need to display something like this
New
----
data row 
data row 
----
New Total
---------
Renew 
----
data row 
data row 
----
Renew Total
================
Grand Total

Comment: that doesn't format very will in the comments I'm afraid... could you pop it in the answer with formatting? Thanks

Comment: okay, from your question update, I've updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks @Jimbo for your help. This modification worked fine for me. But I have made small modification to display sub total for Renew section. It was not shown replaced with your code. I have tweak with if statement at Renew cycle. Thanks again :)